# Inefficient Merge with 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server

This merge statement seems inefficient to me, to insert/update I create a whole new table, then insert into that table then merge, is there a better way?

```
DECLARE @dbEntry TABLE(
Email varchar(100)
,DateRedeemed datetime
)
INSERT INTO @dbEntry VALUES (@Email, @DateRd)

MERGE [dbo].[Redeemers] AS dbTarget
USING
(
SELECT * FROM @dbEntry
)
AS dbSource
ON
(
dbSource.Email = dbTarget.Email
)

WHEN MATCHED
....

WHEN NOT MATCHED 
...
```

PS: This query is simplified for display purposes, there are a lot more columns and a few more operations before and after.

Comment: What you mean it "seems" inefficient to you, and what are you trying to achieve? The statement as given is so generic that it's hard to tell if there's a better solution.

Comment: Is there a way to merge incoming parameters without creating a new table and inserting?

Comment: `whole new table`  It's a table variable, not a table.  There is significantly less over-head creating a table variable than actual persisted, permanent table.  You are also inserting a single row into it.

Comment: Agreed, valid point.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that you're inserting one row. One obvious thing you can do is drop the table variable altogether and simply put `SELECT @Email AS [Email], @DateRd AS DateRedeemed` in your `USING`.

Comment: Perfect, what I was looking for, I like to keep my code short, but my SQL is still in growing stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do that ?

```
MERGE [dbo].[Redeemers] AS dbTarget
USING
(
SELECT @Email as Email, @DateRd as DateRd
)
AS dbSource
ON
(
dbSource.Email = dbTarget.Email
)

WHEN MATCHED
....

WHEN NOT MATCHED 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`MERGE` is designed for processing multiple rows, where the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` decision needs to be made for each row.  It isn't very effective with just one row, because you can just do this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM Redeemers WHERE Email = @Email)
    UPDATE Redeemers SET DateRedeemed = @DateRd WHERE Email = @Email
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Redeemers (Email, DateRedeemed) VALUES (@Email, @DateRd)
ENDIF
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't there an extra SELECT happening in this case?

Comment: @RealityDysfunction: yes, but `MERGE` isn't magic. It, too first has to see if the row exists. If you're going to go for a multi-statement solution, however, you want to put it in a transaction, otherwise the `INSERT` statement can fail or insert duplicates.

Comment: @RealityDysfunction Yes, but if there's an index on `Email` it should be very fast (just an `INDEX SEEK`).  The only way to know for sure if it performs better is to try both and compare the results.  Like I said, `MERGE` is designed for multi-row merging, so it may not optimize as well for one row.